# Сигналы и процессы linux C/C++, Выдает ошибки, как надо исправить?

Tags: c, c++, linux

Здравствуйте Уважаемые программисты, необходимо было написать программу, в тором процесс 1 открывает файл и после этого порождает потомка 2, который в свою очередь порождает потомка 3. Процесс 2 пишет N байт в общий файл, посылает сигнал процессу 3, который тоже пишет N байт в файл и посылает сигнал процессу 1, который считывает данные из файла и выводит их на экран.
Я написал но у меня показывает много ошибок. Помогите пожалуйста найти и исправить данные ошибки!

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define M 10
#define N 5
static struct sigaction act1;
static struct sigaction act2;     // всякие глобальные переменные 
static struct sigaction act3;
int* viv=new int[M];
int* byit=new int[M];
char name[20]="prob.txt";  
pid_t pid1, pid2, pid3;
FILE* f;

void func3(int signo) // обработка сигнала для третего процесса
{
    act3.sa_handler=func3;      // повторная "привязка"  
    sigaction(SIGUSR1,&act3,0);
    printf("treti'i!\n");
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
  {
    byit[i]=i;    // инициализируем массив символов
    fprintf(f,"%d\n",byit[i]);       // пишим его в файл     
  }
    kill(pid1,SIGUSR1);              // отправляем сигнал в первый процесс тем самым "разбудив" егo 
    fclose(f);                       // закрываем файл

}
void func2(int signo) //обработка сигнала для второго процесса  
{
   act2.sa_handler=func2;      // повторная "привязка"  
   sigaction(SIGUSR1,&act2,0);
   printf("vtoroy!\n");
   for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
  {
    byit[i]=i;    // инициализируем массив символов
    fprintf(f,"%d\n",byit[i]);       // пишим его в файл     
  } 
   kill(pid3,SIGUSR1);              // отправляем сигнал в третий процесс тем самым "разбудив" егo 
}
  void func1(int signo)        //обработка сигнала для первого процесса
 {
   act1.sa_handler=func1;
   sigaction(SIGUSR1,&act1,0);   // повторная "привязка"
   f=fopen(name,"rb+");          //повторное открытие файла для чтения
   printf("pervyi!\n");
   for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
   {                                                                
        fscanf(f,"%d",&viv[i]);  // считываем инфу из файла
        printf("%d\n",viv[i]);   // выводим на экран
   }
 }

int main()
{
    f=fopen(name,"wb+");        // создаем файл в первом процессе(которым является запущенная прога)
    act1.sa_handler=func1;

    pid2=fork();                // создаем дочерний процесс 2
    if(pid2==0)    // если его PID нулевой - то мы находимся в нем (т.е. идет второй процесс и все что написано - выполняется в нем)
    {
        act2.sa_handler=func2;   
        sigaction(SIGUSR1,&act2,0);   // задаем обработку сигнала, для второго процесса
        //   alarm(N);                     // функция которая пошлет сигнал к пробуждению процессу в котором она находится через N сек.
        //   pause();                      // до прибытия сигнала (любого, кроме прописанного на игнор) процесс "спит"
        pid3 = fork();              // Создаем третий дочерний процесс
        if (pid3==0)
        {
            act3.sa_handler=func3;   
            sigaction(SIGUSR1,&act3,0);   // задаем обработку сигнала, для второго процесса
            sleep(2); // задеркжка 
        }
        if (pid3<0)
        {
            sleep(1);               // даем время добавить обработчик ("привязка")
            printf("Cann't create process 3: error \n");
            //wait(int *status);            //приостанавление выполнение текущего процесса
            wait(int st);           //приостанавление выполнение текущего процесса
            printf("Process 2: end\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Откуда #include <iostream>, #include <fstream> и for(int i ? Или это с++?

Comment: ой, мой косяк, хотел C++ написать

Answer (score 1):

[[@diga](/users/12771/diga)](/users/12771/diga), а зачем так накручено?

Для этой задачи никакие sleep-ы не нужны. И никакой код в обработчиках сигнала тоже. Достаточно одного (причем пустого) обработчика для всех процессов (он ведь наследуется).

Собственно, достаточно заблокировать сигнал SIGUSR1 в самом начале, а потом в процессах p1 и p3 использовать в нужных местах для ожидания сигнала sigsuspend с маской, разблокирующей SIGUSR1.

Просто последовательно пишите код, как  описали в вопросе. Посылаете сигналы kill-ом из p2 в p3 и из p3 в p1 после завершения записи своей порции в файл.

Не забывайте fflush, перед посылкой сигнала. В p1 сделайте перед чтением rewind.

Ожидать (в wait) достаточно в p1 после вывода на экран.

Если задача еще актуальна, а реализация интересна, то могу набросать код.

--

**Update**

Код для [[[[@Kasper](/users/23126/kasper)](/users/23126/kasper)](/users/23126/kasper)](/users/23126/kasper)

```
/* hashcode avp for @Kasper,  3proc.c

  процесс 1 открывает файл и после этого порождает потомка 2, 
  который в свою очередь порождает потомка 3. 
  Процесс 2 пишет N байт в общий файл, посылает сигнал процессу 3, 
  который тоже пишет N байт в файл и посылает сигнал процессу 1, 
  который считывает данные из файла и выводит их на экран.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define fatal(msg) ({fprintf(stderr, "Fatal <%ld> %s: %m\n", (long)getpid(), (msg)); exit(-1);})

void
fhand (int sig)
{
  //  printf ("pid: %ld catch: %d\n", (long)getpid(), sig);
}

FILE *f;
sigset_t mask;

pid_t
proc3 (pid_t p1)
{
  pid_t p = fork();

  if (p)
    return p;
  // это код, исполняющийся в процессе-3
  sigsuspend(&mask); // ждем команды прдолжить работу

  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  fprintf (f, "Proc3 <%ld> started...\n", (long)getpid());
  fflush(f);
  kill(p1, SIGUSR1); // даем процессу-1 команду продолжить свою работу

  exit (0);
}

pid_t
proc2 ()
{
  pid_t p = fork(), p3;

  if (p)
    return p;
  // это код, исполняющийся в процессе-2
  p3 = proc3(getppid());  // запустим процесс-3, сообщим ему PID процесса-1

  fprintf (f, "Proc2 <%ld> started...\n", (long)getpid());
  fflush(f);
  kill(p3, SIGUSR1);  // даем процессу-3 команду продолжить свою работу

  exit (0);
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char *fname = av[1] ? av[1] : (char *)"3proc.dat";
  if (!(f = fopen(fname, "w+")))
    fatal(fname);

  sigset_t bmask;
  sigemptyset(&bmask);
  sigaddset(&bmask, SIGUSR1);
  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &bmask, &mask);
  signal(SIGUSR1, fhand);

  proc2(); // запустим процесс-2
  sigsuspend(&mask);     // ждем команды прдолжить работу (от процесса-3)

  rewind(f);
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
    putchar(c);

  int st;
  printf ("Parent: <%ld> exits\n", (long)wait(&st));

  exit (WEXITSTATUS(st));
}
```

Компилировал как `gcc 3proc.c`, так и `g++ 3proc.c`

Comment: @avp набросайте код, пожалуйста. Буду благодарен

Comment: @Kasper, можете посмотреть **Update** моего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Где вывод на экран первого процесса? После форка вам необходимо обработать два случая, когда pid==0 и else, а у вас сразу после порождения процесс переходит к return 0 и завершает работу

Comment: В процессе потомке pid == 0, а в родителе соответственно pid равен id потомка, после создания, вероятно, потомка он должен ожидать от него сигнала. Вместо return 0 ожидайте сигнал, и выводите свои данные